# common heading in r data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a header to grouped data in my data.frame structured dataset. please, see the input and output. Input;`

`data<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),  B=c(7,8,9,10), C=c(11,12,13,14), D=c(15,16,17,18))`
Output

[image]

Comment: You can't add a "common header" to a data frame.  A data frame consists of columns.  You can add a spanning header to the printed rendition of a data frame, and you can store *nested* columns (that is, a column of columns) in a tibble.  Please clarify which of these you mean, or expalin what you want of you need something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this for display purposes there are few packages which can help you.

For example, with `knitr` and `kableExtra`.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(data) %>%
  kable_styling(
    full_width = FALSE,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), 
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c(Group1 = 2, Group2 = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, can I ask 1 more question, how can we add rownames to this data?

Comment: `rownames(data) <- c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')` and change the last line to `add_header_above(c('', Group1 = 2, Group2 = 2))`

Comment: can I mark bold some numbers ? for instance if I want to make bold 9 and 17 what can I do? thanks

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question ?

Comment: you can see my question @ronak Shah, thanks